# How to add newline in MSYS2?

Tags: bash, cygwin, msys, msys2

I am trying to add a newline when writing a heredoc to a file but it will just fail.

```
read -r -d '' VAR << EOM
add "main.exe" "/Windows\System32\main.exe" \r\n
add "main.exe" "/Windows\System32\main.exe" \r\n
EOM

echo $VAR > test.txt
```

Result:
add "main.exe" "/Windows\System32\main.exe" \r\n add "main.exe" "/Windows\System32\main.exe" \r\n

Comment: Windows protecting from writing into System32 without admin right access. run msys2 as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a succint way to create a file with Windows line endings in MSYS2, or any Bash environment with the `unix2dos` utility installed:

```
unix2dos > test.txt <<END
here is a line of text
here is another line
END
```

You can use `file` or `hexdump` on the resulting file to verify that the line endings are CRLF:

```
$ file test.txt
test.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

To install the `unix2dos` utility in MSYS2, run `pacman -S dos2unix`.